# Background not aligning

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds

I have following document

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,
 includefoot,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}    
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,backgrounds,shadows,calc}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\newcommand{\newframe}[0]
{   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \draw [black,even odd rule] ($(current page.north
    west)+(1.5in,-1in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(-1in,1in)$);
    \draw [black,even odd rule] ($(current page.north
    west)+(1.45in,-0.95in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(-0.95in,0.95in)$);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\newframe
\input{file1.tex}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\newpage
\newframe
\input{file2.tex}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\end{document}
```

I am unable to put background layer (i.e. two rectangular borders) in background. What is wrong with my code?
I am using texlipse in eclipse and miktex with pdflatex

Desired output is to put two square rectangles around page. Since i have lots of file1, file2 i would really appreciate if \input command stays there.

Comment: I am not applying $fancy pagestyle to any of input document

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: your question is not clear. you want  two rectangular in background of all pages? or just the 2 pages and you have a problem? what is the problem?

Comment: no error. only border which i desired to be in background is being shifted on new page instead. I am suspecting it has to do anything with 'overlay' but i don't know what. @touhami I need to apply background to each input file for each page regardless of number of pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with background package.

`\newframe` for background on `\Noframe` bakgound off.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,
 includefoot,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}    
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,backgrounds,shadows,calc}
\usepackage[
placement=top,
opacity=1,
scale=1,
anchor= below,
vshift=-.9in, hshift=.6cm
]{background}

\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}

\newcommand{\newframe}{%
\backgroundsetup{contents={%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [black,even odd rule] ($(current page.north
    west)+(1.5in,-1in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(-1in,1in)$);
    \draw [black,even odd rule] ($(current page.north
    west)+(1.45in,-0.95in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(-0.95in,0.95in)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}}}}

\newcommand{\Noframe}{%
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}}

\begin{document}
\newframe
\lipsum[1-5]
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\newpage
\Noframe
\lipsum[1-15]
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\newframe
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** Here is a simple code just for test

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}     %just for dummy text

\usepackage[
placement=top,
opacity=1,
scale=1,
anchor= below,
vshift=-.9in, hshift=.6cm
]{background}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,backgrounds,shadows,calc}

\newcommand{\newframe}{%
\backgroundsetup{contents={%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [black,even odd rule] ($(current page.north
    west)+(1.5in,-1in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(-1in,1in)$);
    \draw [black,even odd rule] ($(current page.north
    west)+(1.45in,-0.95in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(-0.95in,0.95in)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}}}}

\newcommand{\Noframe}{%
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}}

\begin{document}
\Noframe
\lipsum[1-15]
\newframe
\lipsum[1-5]
\Noframe
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

First: you need `\Noframe` command to make the Draft background off and than `\newframe` to make rectangle background on.

you can use `\newframe` directly if you need background from the first page.

you can also add `contents={}` to the background package's option

```
\usepackage[
contents=,
placement=top,
opacity=1,
scale=1,
anchor= below,
vshift=-.9in, hshift=.6cm
]{background}
```

and then there will be no Draft background.

Comment: It prints 'Draft' in the background of each page but does not serves the purpose. Rectangles are still appearing on separate page than content. Can you provide me a solution where i can actually use a Tikz Drawing as background?

Comment: @PrachilTambe did you try this code by copy paste? for me it work just fine.

Comment: @PrachilTambe answer edited

Comment: My background.sty does not contains any command called '\backgroundsetup' instead it contains '\SetBgContent' which allow me to set textual contents rather than TikZ contents. Please provide me link to your 'background.sty'. Thanks For your help

Comment: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/background

Comment: Thnaks! replacing the old background.sty helped. Added Edit Also for others